# Making a "folder" in Android app - sqlite or other method?

Tags: android

So I'm making a task management app in Android and have thus far made an implementation that just displays a list of tasks which are store in an SQLite database.

I want to be able to add categories or folders that the tasks can be sorted in to, and planned to do it using a one to many relationship with SQLite but from what I've read SQLite isn't great with foreign keys?

I would appreciate any input or thoughts regarding the best method for doing such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with SQLite - seems the best supported method for Android currently.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing all the logic with java classes and afterwards persisting with [db4o](http://developer.db4o.com/Blogs/Projects/tabid/168/entryid/923/Default.aspx).

Comment: I had considered this but would welcome any other suggestions which are slightly more standard to Android.